# Sorting specific values into time buckets

Tags: r, sorting, binning

I'm dealing with an enourmous problem. I need to distribute some specific values on a specific time bucket structure simply looking at their expiration date (eventually it is possible to compute the expiration period in days or months or years simply subtracting issue date and expiration date).
So basically, what I'm asking for is this. I have these amounts with relative dates:

[image]

and this time bucket structure:

[image]

Is there a way to distribute automatically the amounts in first picture into the time structure above using r? Basically first element should go in "tra 12 mesi e 2 anni", the second element in "overnight", the third element in "tra 12 mesi e 2 anni", and the last in "tra 3 e 4 mesi".

Thank you all

Davide

Comment: Are you sorting by the year, month and day listed in the YY, MM, GG columns, or the difference between the ACC and SCAD dates or what?

Comment: It's unclear how you would want to compute differences. For instance, if I read the first element, it seems that the difference between `ACC` and `SCAD` would be what's reported in the columns `YY`, `MM` and `GG`. But it's not. Also, I don't understand what those three columns (`YY`, `MM`, `GG`) represent for the third element. If your goal is to compute `SCAD` - `ACC` that's a very simple task to do and to label each result based on your time structure.